# Google Map iOS Schema Url show address with name and coordinates

Tags: ios, google-maps

I'm trying to open the Google Map app in iOS using the schema url with coordinates, and I want also to display a name of the location and not the latitude and longitude values.
I'm Doing this now:

comgooglemaps://?q=45.464204,9.189982

And this is the result:

[image]

Can I add a label and hide the coordinates?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to add label via URL schema. What is your intention? Do you want to find the nearest place to this coordinate?

Comment: No I want insert a marker at that coordinate and give it a name

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know if this is possible. I tried also with [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide), but got the same result as via iOS URL scheme.

Comment: @xomena ok, thank you

Comment: Use Appz https://github.com/SwiftKitz/Appz it develops by @Mazyod

Comment: I also have same problem, i achieved to place own description instead of lat/lng with this:
.
comgooglemaps://?q=45.464204,9.189982(\(OwnDescriptionInVariable))
.
but I am still unable to place this description on marker.?